# Can not find Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written some codes by Jquery but because of a reason, it can not find Jquery. I have changed $ to Jquery and still get the same error. What if I change that to the pure JS, any comments on that?

```
var listener = throttle(300, function () {
    slotsAtlantic.forEach(function (item) {
        var $item = jQuery('#' + item.id);
        if ($item.length) {
            var $parent = $item.parent();
            var index = slotsAtlantic.indexOf(item);
            if ($parent.is(':visible') && ((window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) >= ($parent.offset().top - jQuery(window).height() - 300))) {
                googletag.cmd.push(function () {
                    googletag.pubads().refresh([item.slot]);
                });
                slotsAtlantic.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: where's your html?

Comment: Do you have the jQuery script tag in your HTML?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error JQuery not found, it probably means that either you are not including the JQuery script or for some reason, JQuery variable is getting undefined. Can you post your whole html code? Alternately, can you ensure the inclusion of JQuery scripts? E.g. to include JQuery v1.12.0 from  Google CDN, you need to have a script tag like following

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Jquery is included in Package.json. I am pretty sure about it ! This code is for loading "LAZY LOAD" and markup does not play an important role here. This is for the Mrec ads that are supposed to display in Load More

Comment: Maybe JQuery is included after your above scriptlet is loaded. Is it possible for you to include JQuery again  in your HTML?